# Setting osgi.configuration.area breaks my Equinox OSGI app

Tags: osgi, equinox

I have an application which uses Equinox as an osgi framework for a while now. Until now I used the system property osgi.install.area to specify where my bundles are like so

```
${osgi.install.area}/
  plugins/
     org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v20110613.jar
     ... my app bundles
```

Equinox then automatically uses `${osgi.install.area}/configuration` as the configuration area.

Everything works fine.

Now I need to move the configuration area out of `${osgi.install.area}` because that may be read-only and I thought it was as simple as setting `${osgi.configuration.area}` to a suitable path but when I do this the application no longer starts and I have the following stack trace in the logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:150)
...
```

The path is used because at that location the log file is created and a directory `"org.eclipse.osgi"`.

Paths to bundles are referenced in my `config.ini` like so:

```
osgi.bundles=de.mycomp.app-0.6.0.20121116-1834.jar@start, ...
```

The error message does not really give a hint where to look. It must be something rather simple but I am rather clueless at the moment.

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Answer (score 2):

I tested changing the configuration area an existing osgi app and it worked, with the following argument below in the `.ini` file in the root of the install. Are you sure you are setting the config param correctly like this:

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area=c:\mytest
```

After doing that and running the app again, it created the folder and a new configuration.

Here is a copy of my `.ini` file that works, also it's important that osgi params come after and vm args.

```
-loglevel=trace
-vmargs
-Dosgi.configuration.area=c:\mytest
-Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8094
-Declipse.ignoreApp=true
-Dosgi.noShutdown=true
-Dequinox.ds.print=true
```

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem. Can you please help me with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387061/change-eclipse-folder-in-linux