# Change .eclipse folder in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, ide

How can I change the .eclipse folder in Linux? I tried adding this line:

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area=/directory/directory1/eclipse/.eclipse
```

at the top of eclipse.ini but it doesn't work. I've also tried adding it to various other places in the eclipse.ini but still no luck.

### Edit

I have added this line:

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area=file:/directory/directory1/eclipse/.eclipse
```

immediately below -vmargs. When Eclipse starts, it now reads from the correct .eclipse location and if .eclipse does not exist there, it creates it. Unfortunately, after Eclipse has loaded, another .eclipse folder is created in my home folder and Eclipse then continues to read from that folder. I suspect that my eclipse.ini file is now correct but there is another file I need to change.

Comment: is your missing the dash (`-D`) at the beginning a typo or actually what you put in `eclipse.ini`?

Comment: I tried with the dash and without the dash.

Comment: What is the contents/directory listing of the ~/.eclipse?

Comment: you could just try replacing the .eclipse folder with a symlink to where you want it. e.g. `ln -s /path/to/dir/you/want/.eclipse/to/be /directory/directory1/eclipse/.eclipse`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is probably pass java a different `user.home` so that all the other myriad of places that derive a location base it off of `user.home`. So instead of what you have, use this in `.ini` file:

```
-Duser.home=/directory/other/here
```

In addition to .eclipse, you will probably find other directories created in your overridden `user.home`, such as `.p2`, `.oracle_jre_usage`, etc.

Other notes:

`-Dosgi.configuration.area` is the changes the configuration area for Eclipse, it does not effect user area. You also probably don't want to change that setting away from the default unless you really want multiple configurations (read more below).

Additionally, the normal thing to do would be to use `-configuration` as an argument to `eclipse{.exe}` and let eclipse convert it to the appropriate VM argument.

You probably want `-user` though to override the user area. Have a look at [locations in the Eclipse help](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html#locations) for more info (quoted below).

However, there are still things that have individual control over their location, such as secure storage, which is controlled by the `-eclipse.keyring` [command line argument](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-securestorage-options.htm?cp=0_4_3_3).

> **Locations**
>
> The Eclipse runtime defines a number of locations which give
>   plug-in developers context for reading/storing data and Eclipse users
>   a control over the scope of data sharing and visibility. Eclipse
>   defines the following notions of location:
>
> **User (-user) {osgi.user.area} [@none, @noDefault, @user.home,
>   @user.dir, filepath, url]**
>   User locations are specific to, go figure,
>   users. Typically the user location is based on the value of the Java
>   user.home system property but this can be overridden. Information such
>   as user scoped preferences and login information may be found in the
>   user location.
>
> **Install (-install) {osgi.install.area} [@user.home,
>   @user.dir, filepath, url]**
>   An install location is where Eclipse itself
>   is installed. In practice this location is the directory (typically
>   "eclipse") which is the parent of the eclipse.exe being run or the
>   plugins directory containing the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher bundle.
>   This location should be considered read-only to normal users as an
>   install may be shared by many users. It is possible to set the install
>   location and decouple eclipse.exe from the rest of Eclipse.
>
> **Configuration (-configuration) {osgi.configuration.area} [@none,
>   @noDefault, @user.home, @user.dir, filepath, url]**
>   Configuration
>   locations contain files which identify and manage the (sub)set of an
>   install to run. As such, there may be many configurations per install.
>   Installs may come with a default configuration area but typical
>   startup scenarios involve the runtime attempting to find a more
>   writable configuration location.
>
> **Instance (-data) {osgi.instance.area}
>   [@none, @noDefault, @user.home, @user.dir, filepath, url]**
>   Instance
>   locations contain user-defined data artifacts. For example, the
>   Resources plug-in uses the instance area as the workspace location and
>   thus the default home for projects. Other plugins are free to write
>   whatever files they like in this location.
>
> While users can set any of
>   these locations, Eclipse will compute reasonable defaults if values
>   are not given. The most common usecase for setting location is the
>   instance area or, in the IDE context, the workspace. To run the
>   default Eclipse configuration on a specific data set you can specify:
>
> ```
> eclipse -data c:\mydata
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is better than what I was expecting because any other directories created by Eclipse in my home directory, I don't really want there, as I use my home directory in a similar way to a temp directory. My standalone version of Eclipse appears to now be completely standalone.

Answer (score 1):

You must put property definitions like this at the **end** of the eclipse.ini after the `-vmargs` line. If there is no `-vmargs` line you must add one.

So:

```
.... other lines ....
-vmargs
... other arguments
-Dosgi.configuration.area=/directory/directory1/eclipse.eclipse
```