# Change the location of .eclipse directory in linux (from home folder)

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to change the path for the `.eclipse` directory. This directory is in the home folder by default.

Comment: This is discussed in the [multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html&cp=2_1_5_7) section of the help

Comment: Thanks. so I should change `-configuration <location> (Main)
equivalent to setting osgi.configuration.area to <location>`

Comment: Probably but I don't run Linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change .eclipse folder in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387061/change-eclipse-folder-in-linux)