# Change location where eclipse create .eclipse, .p2, and other folders

Tags: windows, eclipse, installation

I see that eclipse create in my user home folder some folders like .eclipse .p2 etc... I want change this default folder(I want save all in a D: location.).
I read this [Change .eclipse folder in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35387061/change-eclipse-folder-in-linux) but I don't understood which file .ini I must change and if I do this before on after eclipse installation. Furthermore I have Windows 10 not Linux.
Sorry for my English. I hope in your help.

This is my eclipse.ini

```
-data  
D:/Programmi/Eclipse  
-configuration  
D:/Programmi/Eclipse/eclipse `  
-startup  
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar  
--launcher.library    
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.550.v20170928-1359  
-product  
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product  
-showsplash  
org.eclipse.epp.package.common  
--launcher.defaultAction  
openFile  
--launcher.defaultAction  
openFile  
--launcher.appendVmargs  
-vmargs  
-D"user.home=D:/Programmi/Eclipse/home"
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8  
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace  
-XX:+UseG1GC  
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication  
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM  
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8  
-Xms256m  
-Xmx1024m  
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Comment: Install Eclipse and before running it edit `eclipse.ini`. I recommend to set [`-data` and `-configuration`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) (add 4 additional lines at the beginning of `eclipse.ini`: first line: `-data`, second line: workspace directory, third line: `-configuration`, fourth line: configuration directory; by default the `.p2` directory will be created in the parent directory of the configuration directory).

Comment: When run eclipse I have again three folder .eclipse .p2 .tooling.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse Installer or did you unzip a package? Where are the folders actually located and where do you expect them to be?

Comment: Unzip. The folder is located in C:\Users\\[userhome] and I Want move in D:\Programmi\Eclipse.

Comment: **Already asked and more details are given here**: [modify eclipse locations...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39168906/how-modify-eclipse-locations-to-prevent-write-to-user-home-directory)

Answer (score 8):

An easy way to do something similar is to move the directory to a desired location and then create a symbolic link to user directory.

Example: The new `.p2` location is `D:\Programmi\Eclipse\.p2`

Open CMD console as Administrator and execute the following:

```
mklink /D C:\Users\your-user\.p2 D:\Programmi\Eclipse\.p2
```

Comment: Yes, I'm a big fan of these sym links in W10. But you have to be careful. This works in this case, but some types of W10 apps, notably system apps, seem to be incapable of using sym links... meaning that you can make your entire system unusable very easily.

Answer (score 6):

Some Eclipse plug-ins store data that are intended to be used by multiple Eclipse installations in subdirectories of your home directory. For example, the *Eclipse IDE for Java Developers* uses following directories:

- `.eclipse`

  - `org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri` - [Automated Error Reporting (AERI)](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/Logging)
  - `org.eclipse.equinox.security` - secure storage for e. g. passwords
  - `org.eclipse.oomph.*` - see *Window > Preferences: Oomph*
  - `org.eclipse.recommenders.models.rcp` - [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/)
  - ...
- `.m2` - Maven repository used by [M2Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/)
- `.p2` - [Equinox p2](http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/p2/) (install/update subsystem)
- `.tooling` - used by the [Eclipse plug-ins for Gradle](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship)

Additional plug-ins might or might not use additional directories to store data.

The trick is to set the home directory used by Java/Eclipse by **adding the following line after the line `-vmargs`** to your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-D"user.home=D:/Programmi/Eclipse/home"
```

Comment: I add this line but don't work. When run eclipse create .p2 and .eclipse folder in user path

Comment: It worked for me on Windows 10 with Eclipse Oxygen.1a. Is `.p2` the only subdirectory that is created in your home directory? What does it contain?

Comment: I both path D:/programmi/Eclipse/home and user path I have .p2 and .eclipse folder but also .tooling folder. The .p2 folder in home directory contain 2 file .info and two folder .core and .engine

Comment: After adding `-D"user.home=D:/Programmi/Eclipse/home"` and before starting Eclipse, did you delete the configuration area (`-configuration`) and the workspace (`-data`)? It might be that there were paths stored to your home directory in it.

Comment: Worked for me, but WITHOUT the quotes, and with different slashes: `-Duser.home=C:\Development`.  Eclipse Oxygen.