# Update/modify the configuration file location of STS/eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I want to keep the copy of my eclipse and spring tool suite in a shared path so that anybody can run the application logged in from their machine and use the common workspace settings.

However, except me when anyone else tries to run eclipse/STS they are getting the below error. I thought it is because of the `.eclipse` settings file is loaded from the `C:/users/user-id/.eclipse`. Apart from this the JDK, JRE etc..  are also configured in the shared path.

So even after relocating this settings file also to the shared path, I am facing the same error. Can some one help me to fix this?

[image: error]

below is the configuration folder

[image: config]

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, I don't recommend you do this. You're better off sharing code in a central git repository than doing it this way.

However, the following SO thread talks about this: [Change location where eclipse create .eclipse, .p2, and other folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866324/change-location-where-eclipse-create-eclipse-p2-and-other-folders) .

Comment: Hi David,  
   The post was helpful But, even after relocating the config location, I am getting the same error. Which means there must be some other issue. I will update my question.